# Do multiple Eternal Thirst give a creature multiple copies of the same triggered ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a creature with two copies of [Eternal Thirst](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Eternal%20Thirst) on it, and a creature my opponent control dies, do I get one or two +1/+1 counters?

Comment: @Rainbolt Not 100% - in that case, the triggered abilities are all on separate creatures, so it's clear that they must all be independent. This one's about a *single* creature having two copies of the same ability. (More like the common double-exalted case, not sure I see one of those here though.)

Comment: @Jefromi If the title of this question were edited to "Can one creature have two copies of the same ability?" then I would consider retracting my close vote. Until then, that's not what it asks, and I think it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Rainbolt That's exactly what it's asking, just in a less generic way. Eternal Thirst grants a triggered ability, and "do they stack?" means "does it get multiple copies". If you think it's not the clearest possible wording, okay - you can edit as well as I can. But that doesn't mean it's a duplicate.

Comment: After the title change, this is now a duplicate of [Do Thorncaster Sliver's trigger abilities stack?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/12634/6692)

Comment: @Rainbolt Coincidentally it was also a duplicate of that *before* the title change, since the title change had no effect on the meaning of the question. (But thank you for finding a duplicate to mark, of course.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get two counters. Each copy of Eternal Thirst grants the creature an independent triggered ability. The two abilities happen to be the same, but there are still two of them. They'll both trigger, both go on the stack (separately!), and each will add one counter as it resolves.

Comment: Ok, thx :) Just to make sure, the lifelinks don't stack right?

Comment: @Niklas, "702.15e Multiple instances of lifelink on the same object are redundant." Note that this does not apply to cards such as Spirit Link, which is worded similarly but does not actually grant the lifelink keyword ability.

Comment: @Niklas Yup, with most basic keyword abilities (flying, trample, menace, lifelink, deathtouch, reach, etc), a creature either has it or it doesn't.